# How to print the latest facebook posts?

Tags: 8, social-network

I would like to show the two latest facebook-posts on my Drupal page.
I found these two modules: https://www.drupal.org/project/facebook_pull and https://github.com/mysequel/Drupal-8-Facebook-Feed-Module. Unfortunately there is no working Drupal 8 compatibility yet. The first one is in Dev Status and I can't even get it to work. The second generates an error when activating.

What is the Drupal 8 way to import this data from Facebook?

Comment: can you edit with the modules that you found?

Comment: I found these two modules: https://www.drupal.org/project/facebook_pull and https://github.com/mysequel/Drupal-8-Facebook-Feed-Module. The first one is in Dev Status and I can't even get it to work. The second generates an error when activating.

Comment: You mean if i could edit a Drupal 7 module to Drupal 8? I am at the very beginning of Drupal module development, so I think it could be too advanced at the moment.

Comment: No, just edit the question with the modules that you found, this can help other users.

Comment: can you take a look to this: https://www.powr.io/tutorials/how-to-add-facebook-feed-module-to-your-drupal-site ?

Comment: let my know if this works

Comment: Sounds like you'll have to build a custom module that outputs a block, fed from data with the Facebook API.

Comment: @adrian-cid-almaguer powr.io did the job for me right now but I have to use the free plan which has a watermark in it . I think my goal is to code a custom module by myself to be more flexible.

Comment: @Kevin Thank you. Yes due to the lack of working D8 modules right now it is the only option to build one by myself.

Comment: @tinytree please see my answer for a D8 module I created. I think it would meet your requirements well.

Comment: for the second option (https://github.com/mysequel/Drupal-8-Facebook-Feed-Module), have you install facebook graph sdk instead? please install with below command : composer require facebook/graph-sdk Thanks

Comment: Another option and probably the most succeeds is the [social feed](https://www.drupal.org/project/socialfeed) module

Answer (score 0):

While the migration of existing modules is done you can use the solution proposed at https://www.powr.io/tutorials/how-to-add-facebook-feed-module-to-your-drupal-site. There is a free version https://www.powr.io/plugins/facebook-feed/standalone?id=9305465& that you can configure for the moment.

Here is the description of it (= quote from the linked page):

> Facebook Feed is free, mobile responsive, and easy to edit; no code
>   needed! Simply embed Facebook Feed to any page, post, sidebar, or
>   footer. Next, customize it right on the live site. Facebook Feed is
>   free and easy-to-use in no time.

Comment: The downvoter, can you says where is the problem? I can try to fix it

Comment: Error message "this is a premium feature, please upgrade".

Comment: @AdamS I can't get the point from your comment, but if you want other solution look in the other answer or try to migrate the existing module that appear in the question.

Comment: I mean that I followed the link in this question and tried to use it, but it kept giving me an error message "this is a premium feature, please upgrade",  hence the downvote.  I get the impressions this solution is not a Drupal module anyway.  I think the other solution is the way to go.

Comment: @AdamS it works for me, But is just 1 feed, to add more you need to upgrade, this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest [Social Wall module](https://www.drupal.org/project/social_wall) that work with Twitter, Facebook and Instagram and provide base functionality to integrate it with other social networks

> This module provides a block that displays feeds from any social
>   network. New social networks and the way they are displayed can be
>   implemented in your module. Available configurations :
>
> Which social networks to display Social networks order Any
>   configuration you set in your custom social network (number of posts
>   to show, ...) New permission Administer social networks